# Javascript defineProperty vs dynamic property definition behavior explanation

Tags: javascript, readonly

What is the Difference between `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'x', ...)` and `obj.x`?

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible), in **non-strict** mode:

```
var obj = { }; 
Object.preventExtensions(obj); 

Object.defineProperty(obj, 
  'x', { value: "foo" }
);
```

throws an error **Cannot add property x, object is not extensible**. But `obj.x = 'foo'` does not throw any error. I don't understand the difference in behavior.

Comment: But it doesn't actually add new property https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQLuU.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Neither technique will work.

What you are seeing is simply that trying to call `.defineProperty` on an object that has had `.preventExtensions` called on it, throws an error and when you use the implicit syntax of `obj.x = foo`, it silently fails.  Silent failures happen quite frequently when you are not in strict mode, which is one of the main benefits of `"use strict"`.

Many of the static `Object` methods (`.preventExtensions`, `.freeze`, `.seal`, etc.) were added with ES 2015 along with `"use strict"` to help bring JavaScript into the modern era. With these new capabilities, we move farther and farther away from some of the native behaviors that have been with JavaScript since the beginning.

```js
"use strict"
var obj = { }; 
Object.preventExtensions(obj); 

// This won't work no matter what mode your in. "use strict" will
// at least make it throw an error rather than silently fail.
obj.x = "foo";
```

Additionally, with **[`.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)**, there are 3 other things that you can configure about the property besides its value:

- configurable
- enumerable
- writable

When you just create a new property, with `object.property = foo`, you are only setting the value and getting the default values for the other 3 configurations.

Comment: +1 , As you mentioned, it appears the assignment failed silently. I checked the value of obj.x and it shows undefined. I checked both Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj) and Object.keys(obj) to verify. Both of them do not show 'x' property.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Exactly. And, my code snippet above shows this as well. It just does it in strict mode so you don't have to chase down an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 0):

An object is extensible if new properties can be added to it. `Object.preventExtensions()` marks an object as no longer extensible, so that it will never have properties beyond the ones it had at the time it was marked as non-extensible. Note that the properties of a non-extensible object, in general, may still be deleted. Attempting to add new properties to a non-extensible object will fail, **either silently** or by throwing a `TypeError` (most commonly, but not exclusively, when in `strict` mode).